# PHP converted string to date not working

Tags: php, string

i have some PHP code that reads the system time, reads a string from a database field that is a date (but the field isn't a date field), converts that string to date and then runs an if statement comparing the two dates.

however for some reason it doesn't seem to be working properly.
I have a simplified version of the code here for testing.

```
<?php
$currentdate = date("d/m/Y");
$textfield = "25/12/2009";
$my_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($textfield));

echo 'Current Date: ',$currentdate,'<br>';
echo 'Selected Date: ',$my_date,'<br>';

if ($currentdate > $my_date) {
    echo "PASS";
} else {
    echo "FAIL";
}
?>
```

the output i get is

```
Current Date: 23/04/2015
Selected Date: 01/01/1970
PASS
```

where have i gone wrong?
windows server running PHP Version 5.3.8

Comment: you should set $textfield = "2009/12/25"; in english format

Comment: i can't set the textfield as that though, as the data in the field i will reading from is in the format "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: OK i think this works, and it appears to give the correct results.
could someone confirm?

`<?php
$currentdate = date("Y-m-d");
$date = '25/12/2009';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
$my_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

echo 'Current Date: ',$currentdate,'<br>';
echo 'Selected Date: ',$my_date,'<br>';

if ($currentdate > $my_date) {
    echo "PASS";
} else {
    echo "FAIL";
}

?>`

Comment: you can use `explode` to reorder date